# Hyperlink in js script inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a super noob and am trying to get the images in this slideshow to link to URLs.

I realize I should have created separate js and html files and I will do that but just want to see if it is possible like this.

THANK YOU!!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var image=new Image()
    image[0]=new Image()
    image[0].src= "hello1.jpg" 
    image[1]=new Image()
    image[1].src="hello2.jpg"
    image[2]=new Image()
    image[2].src="hello4.jpg"
    image[3]=new Image()
    image[3].src="hello3.jpg"
    image[4]=new Image()
    image[4].src="hello5.jpg"
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <img  id="slide" width=1140 height=521 alt="image" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var step = 0
        function slideit(){
            if (!document.images)
                return

            document.getElementById('slide').src = image[step].src

            if (step<4)
                step++
            else
                step = 0

            setTimeout("slideit()",5500)
        }
        slideit()
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so when u click on an image , it should open a link ? or do u want to get images from a website?

Comment: Image should be an array the way you are referencing above when first initializing image it should be var image = [];

Answer (score 1):

Give the img tag a `<a href>` attribute and make an array of links and when the image changes also change the href link.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ...
<body>

    <a id="slideLink"><img id="slide" width=1140 height=521 alt="image" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var step = 0
    function slideit(){
        if (!document.images)
            return

        document.getElementById('slideLink').href = document.getElementById('slide').src = image[step].src;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, from the code above, the browser doesn't know you want to click on the image, there are many ways to accomplish this, but by far the easiest, is to wrap each image tag, in a  tag and the passing a URL to the href attribute of the a tag. Like so... http://www.somewhere.com'>